# Adding a node with MAAS fails

Tags: maas

Ive just built a MAAS cluster to simplify deploying Ubuntu to multiple boxes.

DHCP has been setup properly and I can PXE boot from a server node, yet the node doesn't add to the Dashboard and I get this error until Ubuntu eventually freezes on the login screen for a couple of minutes. What even is this 169.254.169.25 IP address for anyway?

[image]

[image]

I've tried rebooting the server to check if this is a temporary issue, but no luck. There is also no output related to this in the main MAAS log. Can anybody think of a better way of debugging this issue? I'm starting to think it might even be my switch that's screwing things up :/

Comment: Please consider to paste terminal-output as formatted text, it will increase readability a lot. I found this about the mentioned IP-adress: `Computers use addresses starting with "169.254." when they do not have a manually configured address or when they are not told which address to use by a service on the network. They are commonly called the "link local" addresses. ` [Here the source](http://ip-whois-lookup.com/lookup.php?ip=169.254.169.25&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting MAAS and then try again. 169.254.169.254 is the metadata IP from where cloud config is fetched.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, it turns out that I don't have internet connectivity on the PXE network. Make sure you have internet access over PXE.
If you want to switch your PXE to another network, reconfigure MAAS IP using:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
```

You don't have gateway IP set on the PXE network.